# Friend template specialization

Tags: c++

I want to make in-class friend function definition to keep my API consistent in single place. I can't understand how to make that piece of code work and why it doesn't work now
All I want is to create a free function specialization inside a class and keep access to private members

```cpp
template<class T, class R = T>
R lerp(T a, T b, double t) {
    return (1.0 - t) * a + b * t;
}

class Vec {
    double x, y;
public:
    Vec(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    template<>
    friend Vec lerp<const Vec&, Vec>(const Vec& a, const Vec& b, double t) {
        return Vec(lerp(a.x, b.x, t), lerp(a.y, b.y, t), t);
    }
};
```

I searched for [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55943386/6119618) questions and had found it quite hard to understand

Comment: Why not just overload?

Comment: @Jarod42 how do i access private members then?

Comment: I meant `friend Vec lerp(const Vec& a, const Vec&b, double t) {/*..*/}`.

Comment: isn't it specialization itself? What differences?

Comment: it isn't a template (specialization). More reading about [template-specialization-vs-function-overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading).

Comment: You need a separate declaration and definition: https://godbolt.org/z/2s4i4A